# Joomla - Contact form error

Tags: forms, joomla

I have a working contact form in Joomla however when the user submits the form they are taken to a page that doesn't exist so they see the 404 error.

Is it possible to change the page they are taken to after they click submit?

It's a contact page made from a contact in the Contact Manager...

Thanks a lot,
Steph

Comment: Got the answer:

http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=236&t=305421

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your link on contact form is wrong ,just put manually link on it.